# How to add harmonic distortions to guitar amp?

Tags: amplifier, harmonics, guitar-amplifier

I was reading about the carver challenge,(https://www.stereophile.com/content/carver-challenge) and read that he had added a series of potentiometers to one of his amps that had allowed him to independently control each harmonic. I was wondering if this is possible to add to a simple amp design such as this one [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCBsB0BMCsBTAtAdhLa9UE4wGZ8ccBGVEnfMSSEefOuiJZEkgKADMNVYe-CtWLxAlRWDGC79RqWoNm0IJCbCkB3EAooD8Q2ABZw7TQtiGtejPCUmtADiPmjZix1NX8amV4hSASpa0JLD2QSA4SuAgBsp8fuBY7ADmoiEY9mFsAt5+7IEkQmBhyF6SYcqiYNV+0GIJYEmmjhgWBoWtRhoxHc49tJBddpFpfCNqFewA8v2dMeMWeYV8wnxkQiJ9fAAmiJwAhgCuADYALsjHiNui0bVgHMsyW5ubILsHJ+eX1-W30Pf5cK+IHweLRWIgVhg2rwOzaULhQp5TSrUSQCCo9aiOyo3GbTLGFEiEJheGTABOMhJVPR0RINSklNxBNRwOUDLhVlCpM8uRxImBSK0fKJawRQupjIiRSyMrpHM042Ko3KGHYlOyGAhmu58pqdiFuqFbPYsRwKq2yr69WgtFY+H+JC8Bng9jA8DA5EoSn+sHw9QNtOpEpw8UDGJsaIxBO6EzmuMWpoI8yEkcGEDZogA+vYs6gsyQDIJYFnGjUSKX-tUK6wC5XsERUPZIH6iO14K6kwwDCMFOmYtVbjm8wWi3oS2Xq5Xy1naxXGthYq7YDh7Ny3eZ2AAPWRZVdasRqMRGc0AGQAsqh2gAdADOAHtyXeAEaIU6nRDkuztAZGH8xSZFV-aUAOMa5-wMMIRkgjA3j2I4zguK51RAwYQM1CBIFQfUgNA3sw2ufDZjKHZ4M+JDtm-DoyggyZ7xAMIKgHfdGhIGwEESBkQjUbD-Q4jEGK0dh6PSJjuLwcQmyw91UHgWJUHwF0REne4bg4eiyiYs0wngRJD2xIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the article on the Carver Challenge relates to your question.  I searched the page and the word "harmonic" does not occur in it.

If you would like to have knobs to adjust individual harmonics, you should first read up on the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) which can have the effect of multiplying frequency (i.e. generating a harmonic).

To strictly implement the Chebyshev polynomials as transfer functions of a distortion unit in a guitar amplifier, you're better off in the digital domain.  There are even plug-ins for popular digital audio workstations that do just that.

However, if you look at the plots of these functions you may get an idea of their "shape" and how it might be accomplished (not strictly, but maybe efficiently and musically) as a circuit, e.g.: T<sub>2</sub>(x) looks a bit like rectification, and in fact rectification is part of the popular "[octave fuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave_effect#Octave_up)" effect that adds lots of second harmonic.

Comment: The harmonic comment is on page three, but thanks for the mention of octave effects, I hadn't actually considered using rectification to add overtones.

Comment: I ended up loosely attempting this, and it seems to work alright, https://tinyurl.com/yxcx7o2y. This is just an idea at the moment, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Your awful-sounding amplifier already has high distortion. It will have much more distortion when it is clipping (with overdrive).
EDIT: Did you delete your amplifier schematic and scope waveforms?

Comment: My goal is to have independent control of each harmonic, I changed the link because I put the wrong one in the desc.

Comment: The frequency of each harmonic changes when the frequency is changed of the note that is playing. Each harmonic will need one pot to change the frequency and a second pot to change the level of the harmonic.